# Signed arithmetic/control-flow in DCPU-16?

Tags: dcpu-16

DCPU-16 *(the CPU in [Notch's new game](http://0x10c.com/))* doesn't [seem to have](http://0x10c.com/doc/dcpu-16.txt) any signed `IF`/`MUL`/`DIV` instructions.

Is there still a way to do signed arithmetic/control-flow that isn't super incredibly painful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [new DCPU spec](http://dcpu.com/highnerd/dcpu16.txt) published by Notch the other day, does have signed arithmetic instructions:

```
Unsigned  | Signed
==================
MUL       | MLI
DIV       | DVI
SHR       | ASR
IFG       | IFA
IFL       | IFU
```

Comment: That spec is not the one linked to from the front page of 0x10c.com. I'm a little confused...

Comment: This is the new spec which is still open for comments. Notch posted it on reddit the other day. Once it's finalized, it'll make its way onto the 0x10c website.